# Format 64Gb SD without cardreader

Tags: sd-card, samsung-galaxy-note-2, partitions, cyanogenmod

I've installed CM11 on my Sprint Note II, and that thing suddenly won't recognize my external 64Gb SD (whereas stock ROM used to).

I've googled - seems I need to fix the partition. I've tried different options of partitioning and formating in Clockworkmod recovery, still can't see my card.

Some people suggested to fix it on computer and I don't have neither a cardreader nor a machine with Windows at my disposal. And yet even with those, I still have to know what type of partition it should be. Fat, exFat, ext3, ext4?

So, I'm wandering - is it possible to fix a partition table without taking the card out, maybe using `adb shell` with `fdisk` or `parted` or something else?

UPD:

I've tried repartitioning it with fdisk. First I needed to figure out card's block device id. You can do it either by running `blkid` command (and in my case my card didn't even show up in the list). Or instead pull the card out and plug it back, and immediately run `dmesg | grep mmc1` after that. And that gave me this:

```
<6>[  555.585323] c0 mmc1: new high speed SDXC card at address e624
<6>[  555.587975] c0 mmcblk1: mmc1:e624 SU64G 59.4 GiB
```

And then I used `fdisk /dev/block/mmcblk1`, pressed `p` and that shows me this:

```
Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/block/mmcblk1: 63.8 GB, 63864569856 bytes
4 heads, 16 sectors/track, 1948992 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 64 * 512 = 32768 bytes
```

Now based on this information I have to create partition(s), but I have no idea what kind or type. fdisk supports quite a big list. Can you guys advise what to do next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be visible within "Disk Management" (`diskmgmt.msc`) in Windows. From there you can create, delete, modify and format partitions.

Comment: I guess you type faster than you read...

Comment: The question hadn't updated when I submitted that.

Comment: The title specifically indicated "how to do that without taking the card out i.e. using card reader" since the initial submit. Sorry, but your answer is neither relevant nor really helpful.

Comment: Yes, and you can do this with the card still in the phone. Similarly, you comment is neither relevant nor really helpful.

Comment: You know what? I just found a Windows PC, connected my phone, mount the USB in recovery mode, and as you said it found it in Disk Management. I was able to successfully format it into exFAT and now my phone sees it. I am very sorry for acting rude. Although it's your own fault as well. You should've elaborated that in your answer. I had no idea it would work via USB. I do apologise and thank you

Comment: No worries. Glad its sorted anyways. Note to self; more detail next time!

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the most common standard here is FAT32 (which usually ships as format of the only partition with new cards). So using that, you should be on the safe side.

On the other hand: If you have no plans using the card via a card reader on Windows machines, you could also try EXT3 or EXT4. Both should be supported by CM (and also most other ROMs), as with current ROMs EXTFS is used internally as well.

For details, you might wish to check our [file-system](/questions/tagged/file-system) [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/file-system/info), which also links to more information.

Comment: remember the card is 64Gb. There must be some sort of limitations. I remember long time ago I've tried using older version on CM and was in fact able to see the very same card, but if I'm not mistaken I couldn't see the entire volume. And now I can't even partition it right, so CM would mount it

Comment: Yes, there are limits. Many device specs say they support "up to 32 GB". I'm not sure this is a device limit, it could well be the implementation.